# How to produce a line chart from ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, opencv, arraylist, graph, jfreechart

I am performing object tracking on eclipse using OpenCV. I am using one camera to record a RC helicopter fly across my living room. The program works well and bounds the helicopter with a rectangle. I now want to output a graph that would display the helicopter's flight. I essentially save the centers of all of the rectangles in two separate Lists that were initialized as follows:

```
xPositions = new ArrayList<Integer>();  
yPositions = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

I outputted the contents of the Lists in order to test whether the data was indeed being saved, and it worked. I am now effectively lost as to how to take these lists and translate them to my desired chart. I downloaded `JFreeChart`, but am completely unfamiliar with it. I have tried reading some tutorials, but they haven't been that helpful. How would I proceed at this point?

EDIT:

So thanks for the comments guys, especially corsiKa. I ended up using that tutorial and expanding upon it. Now I am having another very minor problem. I want the graph that is displayed to have set axes lengths. That is, I want the x axis to go from 0 to 700 and the y axis to go from 0 to 500. However, my plot axes depend on the data I have. If my x-coordinate ranges between 0 to 300, the x axis only goes from 0 to 300. Anybody know how to fix this issue? So here's my extended class.
public class MakesLineChart extends ApplicationFrame {

```
    public MakesLineChart(final String title, List<Integer> xCoordinatesConstructor, List<Integer> yCoordinatesConstructor ) {

        super(title);

        final XYDataset dataset = createDataset(xCoordinatesConstructor, yCoordinatesConstructor);
        final JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset);
        final ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
        chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(500, 270));
        setContentPane(chartPanel);

    }

    private XYDataset createDataset(List<Integer> xCoordinates, List<Integer> yCoordinates) {


        final XYSeries series1 = new XYSeries("Position");
        if(xCoordinates.size()==yCoordinates.size()){
            for(int i=0;i<xCoordinates.size();i++ ){
                series1.add(xCoordinates.get(i), yCoordinates.get(i));
            }
        }


        final XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();
        dataset.addSeries(series1);


        return dataset;

    }

    private JFreeChart createChart(final XYDataset dataset) {

        // create the chart...
        final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(
            "Position Plot",      // chart title
            "X",                      // x axis label
            "Y",                      // y axis label
            dataset,                  // data
            PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
            true,                     // include legend
            true,                     // tooltips
            false                     // urls
        );

        // NOW DO SOME OPTIONAL CUSTOMISATION OF THE CHART...
        chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);


        // get a reference to the plot for further customisation...
        final XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();
        plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.lightGray);
    //    plot.setAxisOffset(new Spacer(Spacer.ABSOLUTE, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0));
        plot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.white);
        plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.white);

        final XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer = new XYLineAndShapeRenderer();
        renderer.setSeriesLinesVisible(0, false);
        renderer.setSeriesShapesVisible(1, false);
        plot.setRenderer(renderer);

        // change the auto tick unit selection to integer units only...
        final NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
        rangeAxis.setStandardTickUnits(NumberAxis.createIntegerTickUnits());
        // OPTIONAL CUSTOMISATION COMPLETED.

        return chart;

    }

}
```

Comment: Have you googled any tutorials? This one seems like it would be adaptable to what you're doing: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartLineChartDemo6.htm

Comment: Extend `AbstractXYDataset`, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a230513%20%5bjfreechart%5d%20AbstractXYDataset). If you have trouble, please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your current approach.